# Pass optional objects as varags in parameter?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I want to pass multiple optional objects in function as varags ?

```
Optional<ab> ab = Optional.of(ab);
Optional<cd> cd = Optional.of(cd);
Optional<dc> dc = Optional.of(dc);
Optional<ba> ba = Optional.of(ba);
data(ab, cd, dc, ba);
data(Optional<Object>... objects){...}
```

I am getting error if i don this, any suggestion how can be proceed?

Comment: Passing optional as params is bad practice. since make code unreadable IMO.

Comment: An `Optional<ab>` is not an `Optional<Object>` (but you need to decide wheter `ab` is a class or a variable, and class names should begin with an uppercase letter).

Comment: Please quote your error message verbatim in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It isn’t related to varargs. You can’t pass an `Optional<SomeSpecificType>` where an `Optional<Object>` is expected. They are not compatible.

Assume just (without varargs):

```
static void data(Optional<Object> object) {
    // …
}
```

Now if we try

```
    Optional<String> ab = Optional.of("");
    data(ab);
```

In my Eclipse I get this error message:

> The method data(Optional<Object>) in the type MyClass is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Optional<String>)

Java generics are defined with this restriction. You also cannot pass, for example a `List<String>` where a `List<Object>` is expected.

You can overcome the limitation by declaring the method generic too:

```
static <T> void data(Optional<T> object) {
    // …
}
```

Or just like this:

```
static void data(Optional<?> object) {
    // …
}
```

With any of these two declarations the call above is OK.

BTW, @HadiJ is correct in the comment: `Optional` is meant for return values for from methods that may or may not be there. They have very few other good uses, and as parameters is not one of them. It seems to me that for your use case you should just pass the arguments that are there and leave out those that aren’t. The your `data` method may receive a longer or shorter argument array, but will just have to handle all elements of the array without caring about `Optional`. And passing `String`, `Integer`, `LocalDate`, etc, to a method declared `void data(Object... objs)` is straightforward and poses no problem.